# pgadmin can't see postgres when using compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, pgadmin

I've successfully created 2 containers for testing:

```bash
docker container run --name postgres -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password --hostname postgres --network postgres-net -d -v postgres-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgis/postgis

docker container run --name pgadmin4 -p 5050:80 -v pgadmin4:/var/lib/pgadmin -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=me@gmail.com -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=password --hostname pgadmin4 --network postgres-net --detach dpage/pgadmin4
```

Both are in the bridge network `postgres-net` and a named volumed has been created for each one of them: `pgadmin4` and `postgres-vol`

```bash
❯ docker container inspect postgres --format '{{json .NetworkSettings}}' | jq
{
  "Bridge": "",
  "SandboxID": "4a06989f7e03c06b89956681e0f3dd4c400cbeba248d0f418ddf03c8b3e5984e",
  "HairpinMode": false,
  "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
  "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
  "Ports": {
    "5432/tcp": [
      {
        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
        "HostPort": "5432"
      }
    ]
  },
  "Networks": {
    "postgres-net": {
      "IPAMConfig": null,
      "Links": null,
      "Aliases": [
        "abbecb6784e7",
        "postgres"
      ],
      "NetworkID": "15baa0bcadc284342cfd1afde7e7800d1c7aab1045b4cbbca7692293d88cb75a",
      "EndpointID": "7afbf3f5ea0f0bdc3396aee45e0158caf784bb5f371ab67fc847a5fc72e85d56",
      "Gateway": "172.19.0.1",
      "IPAddress": "172.19.0.3",
      "IPPrefixLen": 16,
      "IPv6Gateway": "",
      "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
      "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
      "MacAddress": "xxxxxx",
      "DriverOpts": null
    }
  }
```

For connecting `pgadmin` to `postgres`,  I just needed to make reference to the `postgres` host to make it work.

Then, I decided to move on to compose ...

```bash
PGADMIN_EMAIL=me@gmail.com PGADMIN_PASSWORD=password PGPASSWORD=password docker compose -f docker/docker-compose.yml up
```

...using this compose file:

```bash
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgis/postgis:latest
    hostname: postgres
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'
    networks:
      - gw-net
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${PGPASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - postgres-vol:/var/lib/postgresql/data

  pgadmin4:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4:latest
    hostname: pgadmin4
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    networks:
      - postgres-net
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=${PGADMIN_EMAIL}
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=${PGADMIN_PASSWORD}
    volumes:
      - pgadmin4:/var/lib/pgadmin

networks:
  postgres-net: {}

volumes:
  pgadmin4:
    external: true
  postgres-vol:
    external: true
```

For whatever reason, the `pgadmin4-1` container is not able to connect to the  `postgres-1` container.

```bash
{
  "Bridge": "",
  "SandboxID": "7550d2c28fbc07ab33769c2255aa38ee0ec0c713257aa777e4e9986fd69715fc",
  "HairpinMode": false,
  "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
  "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
  "Ports": {
    "5432/tcp": [
      {
        "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
        "HostPort": "5432"
      }
    ]
  },
  "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7550d2c28fbc",
  "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
  "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
  "EndpointID": "",
  "Gateway": "",
  "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
  "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
  "IPAddress": "",
  "IPPrefixLen": 0,
  "IPv6Gateway": "",
  "MacAddress": "",
"Networks": {
    "docker_gw-net": {
      "IPAMConfig": null,
      "Links": null,
      "Aliases": [
        "docker-postgres-1",
        "postgres",
        "03ea9d1f8933"
      ],
      "NetworkID": "591f1440bf5a4b32e3e348b1eccc9e025cb8da05ed5a6423a7768ae9daf969db",
      "EndpointID": "f4e78d0b454c5eee9537837464d68006e3bee0799d366415949591db2ff3ed26",
      "Gateway": "172.21.0.1",
      "IPAddress": "172.21.0.3",
      "IPPrefixLen": 16,
      "IPv6Gateway": "",
      "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
      "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
      "MacAddress": "xxxxxxxx",
      "DriverOpts": null
    }
  }
}
```

I get this error:

> Unable to connect to server:
>
> could not translate host name "docker-postgres-1" to address: Name does not resolve

I also tried using "postgres" without success. I can see that the maintenance database i've specified exists and that the use exists as well.

Comment: What is 'gw-net'?

Comment: Shame on me, I'll go straight to the eye doctor (or get some sleep) Obviously the 2 containers must be on the same network and I forgot to put the postgres container into the `postgres-net` one :/ Thank you @jjanes (you can post the answer) `gw-net` is the gateway network because I have other configuration in the compose file but removed it for simplicity. For those interested, there's a gateway,  a backend api,  and a database each belonging to their network and the backend api belongs to both the gateway network and the database network.